# C# - Simultaneous HttpWebRequest in order to get a response from server

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, http, httpwebrequest

I'm currently working on a C# download manager (WinForms) as a project of mine and I've faced a problem which I'm not sure what the best approach would be.

I want to 'force' a response from a web server at optimal time. Having that in mind, I figured it would be best to send requests repeatedly with a certain interval until one of the requests is answered. Assuming the server is responsive, this should eliminate some of the delay.

For example,
I want to retrieve information from a web server. I don't want to send a request and wait for it to timeout and then re-send. Instead I would wait 2 seconds and send another request and then another until one of them is answered.

1. Am I entirely wrong with this re-sending approach? Should I just send one request and wait for a response?
2. What would be a good solution for this? Using several Tasks with the same cancellation token?
   Asynchronous requests with a signal?

Would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey! Still there? =) Just want to know whether you solved your problem. I noted that you are new in StackOverflow... when you find that an anwer is the solution for your problem, then you can mark it as being the "accepted answer". If none of them correspond to what you want, don't accept an answer just to make people happy... ok!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that most of the download managers parallelize pieces of the file being downloaded... not exactly the startup of the download. I don't think you should care about forcing a fast response, actually I think it won't help.

When you make a request it is going to find it's route to the server and then back again. Once you know the route, the next time is going to be fast... that is, if you make multiple requests using a lot of threads, all of them will probably be answered at the same time, because the route is yet being 'discovered', and once it is discovered all of them will use the same path.

As matter of how to do it... I would do it using asynchronous requests.

But that is only my opinion... that is all of this is just my opinion... just what I think is true.

Answer (score 0):

If your using .Net 4.0, you can try the parallel processing.
Something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ListOfRequest, req => {
     // Retrive information from a web server.
});
```

Or you can checkout this link for your token thing cancellation for job:
[Parallel Programming: Task Cancellation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx)

Hope this help, thanks.

Comment: I read the blog's articles about TPL, it was very helpful, thanks for linking it.
I decided to go with one request at a time to retrieve info and then put tasks to use for simultaneous connections.
Thank you both for your answers.